# Redux-toolkit middleware that appends a queryParam to an url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, middleware, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to set up a middleware which would attach a "locale" queryparam to all my requests with a language which are stored in a redux store.
I'm not sure how would I do that, but here's the example of what I've tried, but don't have an idea how to access the URL.

```
const myMiddleware = store => next => action => {
  const chosenLang = store.getState().language.chosenLang;
// **is it possible to access an url inside this middleware?**
  ....
}


const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
     .......
    },
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware().concat(myMiddleware)
  });
```

Comment: This seems like something you would do in React router, not in redux. May I ask why you want to do this?

Comment: I'd like to "catch" all the requests that my app sends to the server, and attach 
"?locale={language}" instead of adding this to urls in every service where i send requests. 
The reason why I can't just create a helper function for adding it is that this 'language' is stored in a redux store, so I would need access to it too, so I guess it would be nice to add this somewhere inside a redux so I can easily access the store.

Comment: Maybe store the locale in localStorage and make an Axios interceptor?

Comment: Thanks Neil, will try that, but I'm not sure how it would work since I'm actually making a hybrid app to work on various platforms, that's why I wasn't about to use the localStorage in the first place, but now it looks like the only option. 
Thanks!